# My five daughters

Tags: number-theory, calculation-puzzle

The sum of the ages of my five daughters is 43. The ages of any two of them have a common factor greater than 1. How old are my daughters?

Comment: The number of partitions of  a number (such as this partition of 43) that can be recovered uniquely from their graph of common divisors (or P-graph) are counted in http://oeis.org/A298676.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure if it's unique, but this works:

> 15, 10, and triplets of 6 years old.

The common factors:

> 2, 3 and 5.

How I found it:

> Starting from the fact that any two have a gcd greater than 1, I assumed that all three have exactly two small prime factors. I assumed at least 2 and 3 for those. Starting with 6, 6 and 10, I had 21 years left, which can come from 6 and 15.

Comment: The difference between 2 of the triplets is still factor 1? how would that work?

Comment: The question states they must have a common factor *greater* than 1, which they have. They have three, even: 2, 3 and 6

Comment: Ok, I guess my mind is just a bit boggled about this then.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus  GCD(6,6) = 6, not 1.

Answer (score 19):

Here is another solution. Your daughters are ages

> 43, 0, 0, 0 and 0 (congratulations on your new-born quadruplets!).

This works, because

> zero is divisible by every non-zero integer, and therefore all five ages share the common divisor 43.

Comment: That's cheating! But very clever.

Comment: This answer is almost a winner but is not valid. Because they don't share a divisor, they share a factor. you cannot factor those *[spoiler]* numbers together, so this is not valid.

Comment: @Mindwin 43 is a factor of itself and is also a factor of 0. We have 0=43*0.

Comment: @drhab zero is not factorable. It is explicitly excluded in the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) Zero has no prime factors. But people use too loose definitions when stating that theorem, that leads to `43*0=0`.

Comment: @Mindwin I agree that 0 does not have a prime factorization, but it seems to me that 0 = 43*0 is still a factorization of 0, just like 24 = 4 * 6 is a factorization of 24 (just not a prime factorization).

Comment: @MarcPaul Ok. I'll nail this as a lack of rigour on the puzzle. It indeed does not say nothing about prime factoring.

Comment: I’m torn (you might even say **divided**) on this. On the one hand, it’s clearly not the answer the OP was looking for.  On the other hand, I also got this answer, and I would have posted it if nobody else had.

Answer (score 13):

Your daughters are

> 6, 6, 6, 10, and 15

It is obvious that the sum of those ages is 43. For each pair the common factors are:

> gcd(6, 10) = 2,
>  gcd(6, 15) = 3,
>  gcd(10, 15) = 5,
>  and gcd(6, 6) is obvious.

The only remaining question is whether that is the only possible solution. My first observation was that

> 43 is a prime thus the ages cannot all have a single prime factor in common.

I also realized that since each pair have a common factor

> There must be at least 3 different prime factors involved such that each pair can share a factor without all three sharing a factor. (If there were only 2 factors involved one of them would have to be shared among all the daughters or there would be a pair of daughters not sharing a factor).

The smallest sum we can achieve is by using

> The three smallest primes as factors making the possible ages 6, 10, and 15. And there would have to be three of age 6 for a total of five daughters. Any other approach will result in a larger sum than 43.

Comment: While I'm also convinced that there's just one solution, I'm not sure your proof is completely rigorous, specifically the part of requiring at least 3 factors. What would the problem, in case of 2 factors, be with one factor being shared among all of them?

Comment: @Lolgast If $p$ is a common factor of $n_1,\dots,n_5$, then $p\mid n_1+\dots+n_5=43$, so $p=43$. But then the sum is at least $5\cdot 43$.

Comment: So in the case of two factors $p,q$, there is one child omitting $p$ and another child omitting $q$, and that pair of children has a gcd omitting both.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Ah of course... I should've thought of that. Guess I'm not fully awake yet.

Comment: An emphatic +1. IMHO, this should be the accepted answer, because (1) it was posted first (although, peculiarly, it was flamboyantly wrong at first), and (2) it has a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider the new born option (the fact that 0 is divisible by any number :) ) I would add this **[0,6,10,12,15]** to **(0,0,0,0,43)**.

But the only solution to this is the first one **(6,6,6,10,15)**.

The way I found these solutions is by thinking in a brute force way and since the number of combinations is high, I wrote a program that took a minute or less to finish and gave me the desired output.

Comment: Bravo! I got the first two answers, and I missed this one.  But I don’t understand your second paragraph.  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.)  And I’m tempted to downvote because you don’t list the numbers in numeric order.

Answer (score 1):

If all the ages are different, here is one solution.

> 0, 6, 10, 12, 15

Comment: This is the same as [Rihab’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58287/19765#58317).   But +1 for listing the numbers in numeric order, and using spoiler markdown.